# Archive upload Error while trying to publish app to app store

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

Trying to publish our first app and stuck with above error. Tried a lot but unable to resolve it. is anyone can guide me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a temporary error. Try again later.

Answer (score 0):

Please validate your archive first from Xcode before directly uploading to App Store. If there is an error, then it will show you so you can trace the bug.

Comment: While Validating. Upload button is enabled but it gives same error while trying to upload also.

Comment: did you set Generic iOS Device before archiving the build... ?

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: did you try to upload archive with Application Loader... ? May be it will work...

Comment: Or have you installed any anti-virus in your system... If so then please turn it off and try again...

Comment: how I can upload with Application Loader?

Comment: Open application loader and login it with your apple id